# GCC C++/G++ [NOT VC++] connect to MySQL on Windows 8.1 (MinGW/Cygwin) and Installing Connector/C++ from Source

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Please help fix the error on Installing Connector/C++ from Source, while "make clean". There are two parts to the question:

**Part 1 of the Question:** What is the error (cdk/parser/CMakeFiles/cdk_parser.dir/flags.make) missing separator?

```
[E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++>git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp
Cloning into 'mysql-connector-cpp'...
remote: Counting objects: 16511, done.
remote: Total 16511 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 16511
Receiving objects: 100% (16511/16511), 7.77 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13018/13018), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (739/739), done.

E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++>cd mysql-connector-cpp

E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++\mysql-connector-cpp>"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DWITH_BOOST="E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++\Boost\Unix-Varia
nts\boost_1_63_0"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Building on system: Windows-6.3.9600 (AMD64)
Using cmake generator: MinGW Makefiles
Using 64bit generator
Building shared connector library
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
Configuring CDK as part of MySQL_CONCPP project
WITH_TESTS: OFF
CDK include path: E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/include;E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/include
-- Performing Test HAVE_MOVE_SEMANTICS
-- Performing Test HAVE_MOVE_SEMANTICS - Failed
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
Configuring Protobuf build using cmake generator: MinGW Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
Using pthreads for protobuf code
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf
Protobuf include path: E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.0/src
WITH_SSL: OFF
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR - Failed
-- Looking for sys/endian.h
-- Looking for sys/endian.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h - not found
-adding static library: cdk_mysqlx_objs
-adding static library: cdk_proto_mysqlx_objs
-adding static library: cdk_foundation_objs
-adding static library: cdk_parser_objs
Merging static libraries into cdk:
 - cdk
 - protobuf-lite
 - cdk_mysqlx_objs
 - cdk_proto_mysqlx_objs
 - cdk_foundation_objs
 - cdk_parser_objs
Wrote configuration header: E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/include/mysql/cdk/config.h
Connector library name: mysqlcppconn2
Connector library will be installed at: lib64
Install location: C:/Users/Aspire/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 2.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-cpp

E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++\mysql-connector-cpp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe" clean
cdk/parser/CMakeFiles/cdk_parser.dir/flags.make:6: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make\[1\]: *** \[cdk/parser/CMakeFiles/cdk_parser.dir/clean\] Error 2
make: *** \[clean\] Error 2

E:\Working\SQL\MySQL\C++\mysql-connector-cpp>][1]
```

Please note that [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) has been installed successfully and is working fine as evident from the following output of example.cpp:

```
$ c++ /e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/Boost/Unix-Variants/example.cpp -o example \
> -I /e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/Boost/Unix-Variants/boost_1_63_0 \
> /e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/Boost/Unix-Variants/boost_1_63_0/Boost-Build/boost/bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-mingw-5.1.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_regex-mgw51-mt-1_63.a

$ ./example.exe < /e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/Boost/Unix-Variants/jayne.txt
Will Success Spoil Rock Hunter?
```

**Part 2 of the Question:**

Also, tried in vain the GCC C++/G++ [NOT VC++] connect to MySQL on Windows 8.1 (MinGW/Cygwin) as in the [Getting Started with Connector/C++: Usage Examples - Example1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html):

```
$ g++ -o Example1 Example1.cpp \
> -I /e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/Boost/Unix-Variants/boost_1_63_0 \
> -I/e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64/include \
> -I/e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64/include/cppconn \
> -L/e/Working/SQL/MySQL/C++/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64/lib/mysqlcppconn

C:\Users\Aspire\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDVNizG.o:Example1.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__imp_get_driver_instance'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help explain the error: undefined reference to `__imp_get_driver_instance', although perhaps the wrong library (format) mysqlcppconn.lib (mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64) linked while compiling, and possibly help resolve this error.

Comment: What are the errors you got? Also if it is         a problem of connection then ensure that you installed Mysqld service and is it running?

Comment: Please note that the question has been modified with more details.  And help with solution.